# XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

**UPDATE**: this exception is ***occasionally*** thrown by Maven, cannot understand why build results vary...

Hi all,
when I deploy my web application on a different machine other than mine I receive this Exception when I try to open XLSX files with

`Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(IVENTORY_TEMPLATE));`

Here it is the complete stacktrace:

```
 

       java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to     org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
            at __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder(__DocumentBuilderFactory.java:122)
            at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.newDocumentBuilder(DocumentHelper.java:84)
            at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.readDocument(DocumentHelper.java:137)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:374)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.(ContentTypeManager.java:100)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.(ZipContentTypeManager.java:54)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:257)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:774)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:308)
            at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:261)
            at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:222)
            at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:201)
            at it.habble.servlet.inventory.InventoryBuilder.processFile(InventoryBuilder.java:680)
            at it.habble.servlet.inventory.InventoryServlet.doPost(InventoryServlet.java:155)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
            [..]
```

I'm using POI 3.15 in a multi-module maven web application (web, ejb, jpa) packaged as an EAR archive.
Here it is my maven dependency tree from EAR project

```
    [INFO] maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ habble-ear ---
    [INFO] it.habble:habble-ear:ear:1.0
    [INFO] +- it.habble:habble-report:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
    [INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.15:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.15:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.15:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.04:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-excelant:jar:3.15:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.15:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.15:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:openxml4j:jar:1.0-beta:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4.01)
    [INFO] |  |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2.17)
    [INFO] |  +- org.jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.19:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.23:compile
    [INFO] |  +- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9.0)
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:138:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |        \- (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- (jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4.01)
    [INFO] |  +- (it.habble:habble-common:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (com.google:gcm:jar:0.0.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- it.habble:habble-ejbs:ejb:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.15:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9)
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.15:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.15:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.3.0)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-contrib:jar:3.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.15)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
    [INFO] |  |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.2.17)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi-excelant:jar:3.15:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:ooxml-security:jar:1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:openxml4j:jar:1.0-beta:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (it.habble:habble-ejb-client:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  \- (it.habble:habble-jpa:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- it.habble:habble-ejb-client:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4.1208.jre7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-api:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:r08:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-impl:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-api:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:r08:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-api:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- (org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-api:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-ui:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-api:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  \- (org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-api:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  \- (it.habble:habble-jpa:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- it.habble:habble-web:war:1.0:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.4:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- opensymphony:ognl:jar:2.6.11:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.6.RELEASE)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-faces:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (opensymphony:ognl:jar:2.6.11:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.webflow:spring-js:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js-resources:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.9.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.6.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.5.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.5.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.5.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-remoting:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-openid:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- org.openid4java:openid4java-nodeps:jar:0.9.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.8.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.20:runtime
    [INFO] |  |  \- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime - omitted for conflict with 2.11.0)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.3:runtime - omitted for conflict with 4.5.2)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.8.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:jar:3.3.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.21)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.21)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.21)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.1)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime - omitted for conflict with 2.11.0)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- (xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime - omitted for conflict with 2.11.0)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.1)
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4)
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.1)
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4)
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0GA:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime - omitted for conflict with 2.11.0)
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime
    [INFO] |  |  |     \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:runtime
    [INFO] |  |  |        \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.4.01)
    [INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.21)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.8.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
    [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.3.RELEASE)
```

Can you spot a misconfiguration or do you have any advice on how to solve this issue? We're pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the Excel files (created both with Excel 2007 and OpenOffice).

Comment: I would check for the Xerces dependency - try to downgrade it or check your AppServer for a conflicting version. If you can set the classloader order, try parent_last. So this error occurs in the Maven build AND on the AppServer?

Comment: Thanks, I looked better to Maven dependencies to find out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed `org.apache.poi:poi-contrib`, `org.apache.poi:ooxml-security` and schemas. I had to consider all those messages like "omitted for duplcate|conflict" regarding these libraries. Leaving xml-beans 2.6.0 (recommended version by Apache POI developers) and all POI libraries with the same version seems to fix the problem